# Bootstrap hidden element extends past container when expanded

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website that displays many real-time graphs and gauges, all hidden within drawers initially. The graphs are made with the plotly.js library. The gauges are done with JustGage. The code for the containers is as such:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-5 statistics">
        <div class="centered-text">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="panel panel-info">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-heading">Statistics Panel</h3>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="list-group">

                        <!-- Base Station Panel -->
                        <li class="list-group-item">
                            <div class="row toggle" id="dropdown-detail-1" data-toggle="detail-1">
                                <div class="col-lg-10 text-left">
                                    Base Station
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-2"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i></div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="detail-1">
                                <hr></hr>
                                <div class="container-fluid">
                                    <div class="fluid-row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <div id="happygraph1"></div>
                                            <input id="happybutton1" type="button" value="View History"
                                                   onclick="happygraph1.changeMode();"/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <div id="happygraph2"></div>
                                            <input id="happybutton2" type="button" value="View History"
                                                   onclick="happygraph2.changeMode();"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="fluid-row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <div id="happygraph3"></div>
                                            <input id="happybutton3" type="button"
                                                   value="View History" onclick="happygraph3.changeMode();"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="container-fluid">
                                        <div class="fluid-row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <div id="happygauge1 style="height: 250px; width: 300px;"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <div id="happygauge2" style="height: 250px; width: 300px;"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The issue is that when the page loads, if the data begins appearing on the graphs before the hidden element is expanded, the graphs' containers extend out of the newly expanded element. However, if the element is expanded first, and then the data comes in, it acts exactly how it should. There is no issue with the gauges.

Here is a screenshot of when it's working:
[graph containers stay within element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLcF6.jpg)

Here is a screenshot of when the element is expanded after the data has started being drawn: [graph containers expand out of element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6KlK.jpg)

The drawers (and the layout in general) is done up by bootstrap. What is causing the containers to break? I have tried playing with the fluid row and container properties, however to no avail. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue was not with Bootstrap at all but with some of the layout options set in Plotly. Plotly was sizing the graphs to be much larger than the container only when loaded hidden.